# Batch Script to convert 1 image and 1 audio from image directory and audio directory into mp4

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ffmpeg, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a folder of images and a folder of audio, I'm trying to create a script that takes an image from the image directory, merges it with an audio from the audio directory and outputs an mp4 but not having much success:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.aac

    do
    {
      aac=`basename $f.aac`
      jpg="${name}.jpg"
      output="${name}.mp4"

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i $jpg -i $aac -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest $aac 
    }
done;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `name` is unassigned. `output` is not used.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through your script.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

You tagged this question with `bash` and `ubuntu`, so you probably want to change this in:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

[...] takes an image from the image directory, merges it with an audio from the audio direrctory and outputs an mp4

I don't see any directory name in this, so your files won't be found. Normally, I set the directories in variables, that allows easier change of the script. So:

```
aacdir=/home/me/aac
jpgdir=/home/me/jpg
mp4dir=/home/me/mp4
```

Then you say, you take "mage from the image directory". No, you don't. You take a sound file (and not from the sound directory). So, that for loop would actually need to be:

```
for file in "$jpgdir"/*.jpg ; do
```

Then you start mangling the file-names. To see what you're doing, I assume you start with `$f`=`/home/me/hoppa.aac`

```
  aac=`basename $f.aac`
```

`aac` is now `hoppa.aac.aac`

```
  jpg="${name}.jpg"
```

`jpg` is now `.jpg` ; because name is empty.

```
  output="${name}.mp4"
```

`output` is now `.mp4` for the same reason.
This is certainly not what you want.

For future projects: if the command does not work, echo everything, so you know what your variables contain. In this case, I would add:

```
echo "aac=$aac ; jpg=$jpg ; output=$output"
```

to see what is going on.

What you probably want is:

```
base=$(basename "$file")
stripped=${base%.jpg}
aac="$aacdir/$stripped.aac"
jpg="$jpgdir/$stripped.jpg"
mp4="$mp4dir/$stripped.mp4"
```

Once again, just echo the values in your script if you are uncertain or if you think that I might have made a mistake (that happens).

I assume your ffmpeg is correct (mostly), but I would like to point out two things:

- Quote your variables when you use them
- The last argument of `ffmpeg` should be the output file, not one of the input files (I seem to remember)

That would make it:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "$jpg" -i "$aac" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest "$mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and very easy to follow explanation! A lot of different questions I had were answered :) The echo tip is gold, I'll use it a lot!
The current result is that the image and audio file need to match in file name, if there a clever way where they don't have to? @Ljm